# Creating object in RaphaelJS

Tags: javascript, raphael

Is it possible to create Raphael's object but not drawing it on paper?

In example, i want to create circle, do some actions and show it on callback of actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need what is called an "offscreen canvas", something that is currently not implemented in html5 (some people [talk about it](http://www.mail-archive.com/whatwg@lists.whatwg.org/msg19383.html)).

Maybe you can create a canvas and set the css to `display: none` or `visibility: hidden`, and copy the image data from one canvas to the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this construct:

```
var foo = circle(whatever).hide();
```

and then later use 
    foo.show();

inside whichever callback. it creates the circle object (you can see it in the dom) but you won't see it on the raphael paper